# Projects Browser Preview in Aptana

Tags: php, configuration, aptana, preview

I installed `Aptana Studio 3 (Mac)` and I would want to manage projects like I can do with `Dreamweaver`, that is I can define a local (testing) server for each project with a dedicated url: this could be **localhost/projectname** or **projectname.local** using virtual hosts. The second option (virtual hosts) would be very appreciated.

I would want to click-preview (clicking the run button or something similar) any file in a project with the default setting of the related project.

Can anyone help me?

My attempts with Apache MAC OSX Mountain Lion:

**Web Project:**
I created a web project and I added two html files, then I set up preview settings of the project (adding a simple web server called 'ApacheServer' with `http://localhost` and document root). But if I apply this setting this seems to be override from aptana default 'Built-in server', because when I come back to property panel 'Built-in server' is selected'.
When I click on "run" from the menu or from the "play button" it starts always the browser using 'Built-in server'. Ok I view the page but with default settings, my settings are ignored!?
I think that I have to create a web browser configuration clicking on "run configuration" and choosing the created web server (I had to create external web server because simple web server cause problem 'Generic server doesn't support start')..
However now I have my browser configuration but the only way to use it on each page in the project is to select the dropdown list near the "play button" and select my browser configuration...uncomfortable :)
If I click directly on "play button" the page start with default browser configuration!
Can't I set a default browser configuration (created by me) for a single project?

**PHP Project:**
I created a php project and I added two php files, when I open a file and click "run" it doesn't open this page but it opens last page run (this could be a preference setting, i have to check). If I right click on the file in the projects tree and then I click run as server it asks me the launch url. But this launch url is the last used, not a default launch url set for the project…so also this is uncomfortable ;)
Here I noticed that in "run configurations" aptana creates each run page and store there launch url settings.
So it seems that aptana setup run/preview configuration foreach page and not for each project, or however a default launch configuration can't be set different for every project…

Anyone knows how to do that or has some ideas?
Ultimately I would want that every page in a project could be launched using a default preview configuration in an external browser. This configuration should be different for each project (this could be useful having different urls for each projects using virtual hosts configuration.

**I found a possible solution:**
In "run configuration" you can create a web browser configuration for each project, setting up dedicated url for each project (using option "use base url").
Then when you want to view a page in the browser you can click the dropdown near the "play button" and select related browser preview configuration. If you don't find a configuration in the dropdown you have to launch it first from "run configuration" window.

I don't understand so much run/preview configurations and the difference between browser preview and "run as php server"...perhaps you have to setup a run configuration (and not web browser) if you want to debug?

I know how dreamweaver works and I thought that Aptana could manage websites and preview (for each project) but perhaps I was wrong!? :)

Someone knows something about it and how to configure them?
Can you explain some "case studies" about how you manage launch preview and run mode when you work with aptana?

thanks
bye

Answer (score 0):

Check out the  link below, in the last section they are doing something similar to what you want.
The settings are bound to Aptana so OS platform should not be an issue. 
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/aptana-studio-3-guided-tour-and-tutorial-create-a-web-project-using-the-html-5-boilerplate-framework.html#fbid=N9B8varcFW1

Comment: I followed this tutorial but this ends before to explain "Runtime Configuration and Preview Settings" :)
Now I'll report in the original post my attempts and encountered problems.

Comment: Yeah thats an extremely unhelpful link.